# Program binaries or files with same MD5 hash

Tags: hash, md5

I'm looking for 2 different program binaries or 2 different files with the same MD5 hash to prove its weakness and the collisions in the algorithm.

Comment: Quite similar post are discussed here: 
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the samples at [MD5 Collision Demo](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/).

Answer (score 8):

- [This page](http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/people/lucks/HashCollisions/) has a pair of PostScript documents that have an MD5 hash collision.
- [This page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bdeweger/CollidingCertificates/) has a pair of X.509 certificates that have an MD5 hash collision.
- Wikipedia also [has a pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) of hexadecimal strings that are very similar and yield an  MD5 hash collision (when hashed as raw binary data).